# Как задать шаблон для preg_match?

Tags: preg_match, php

Например надо найти url картинки тут (это часть большого текста, где расположена нужная картинка):

```
 <div class="doc-banner-icon"><img src="https://lh3.ggpht.com/0RHA6wgcdzFtGxINiNohDV9ppDaVsz_1z-KXI8GKO-kFRu6fs5T4nXlz1kDaGLcohQ=w124"></div>
```

Какой вообще принцип задания шаблонов?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы искал начало "`<img`"
дальше пока не закроется "`>`"
искал "`src=\"(что-то кроме \")`, 
`"`

Не проверял, но примерно так:

```
#<img[^>]+src="([^"]+)"#
```

**Upd**. проверил на том фиддле, [работает](http://pix.am/CRjT/) (скриншот) : )

Answer (score 3):

```
preg_match_all('/<img[^>]*?src="([^"]*)"[^>]*>/i', $HTMLstr, $matches);
```

В $matches[1] будет массив со всеми URL. Только что делал для себя данную задачу.

Comment: чтот у меня получается $matches[1] - массив с размерность 0

Comment: А переменная $HTMLstr что из себя представляет? Дайте ссылку на pastebin, например.

Comment: попыталась вывести значение этой строки. вышло :
Moved Temporarily
The document has moved here.

Comment: вот и ошибка в этом была=)

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте таким образом:

```
preg_match_all('/src=["](https:\/\/.*?[^"]+)/i', $str, $matches);
```

Comment: $matches [0][$i] и $matches[1][$i] ничего не выдают

Comment: @Евгения Форманюк, Значит, вы что-то не досказали. Смотрите [пример в действии](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/rf4-pum).